# how to increment a shared_ptr like you would a normal pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, smart-pointers

I'm trying to print a char array in reverse using c++ smart pointers. I run into two problems. 1 is a runtime error that i'm trying to debug, the other is the fact that every time I have to increment the shared_ptr I have to use the get() method.

I'm pasting both of my functions. One that reverses a string using just pointers. 
and one that uses shared ptr.

```
    int display_string_reversep(char* astring)
{ 
  char* achar = astring;
  if((*achar) != '\0')
    {
      char* x= achar;
      x++;
      display_string_reversep(x);
      cout<<(*achar);
    }
    return 0;
} 
int display_string_reverseup(shared_ptr<char> astring)
{ 
  shared_ptr<char> achar(astring);
  //if((*achar) != '\0')
  if(achar != nullptr)
    {
      if(*(achar.get()+1) != '\0')
    {
      shared_ptr<char> x(achar.get()+1);
      //x++;
      display_string_reverseup(x);
    }
      cout<<(achar);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to c++11 and this was just a little exercise that I was putting myself through. 
The internet has given me no other way to increment a shared pointer so far. Is there ?

```
char astring [] = {'F','e','l','l','o','w','\0'};

  display_string_reversep(astring);
  display_string_reverseup(shared_ptr<char>(astring));
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate how you intend to initialize the `shared_ptr` version of `astring`?

Comment: That's a _very_ strange use of a shared pointer. A shared pointer to T "protects" just one instance of T. Not an array of Ts. Doing pointer arithmetics on shared pointers doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @Mat So if I was to do pointer arithmetics what sort of smart pointers could I use ?

Comment: @Mat: Shared pointers can encapsulate an array just fine. However he should be using a `shared_ptr<char[]>`

Comment: Essentially you don't. You use container classes to avoid the whole pointer arithmetic business. And `std::string` rather than `char*` for strings.

Comment: @Lightness: sure. I think my comment is still correct though, even for T an array type.

Comment: What you are asking IS a thing, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2388.pdf, but still not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not increment a `shared_ptr`.

A `shared_ptr` is a reference-counted pointer to a memory node. Its purpose is to `delete` the node when the reference count drops to zero. It is not a replacement for a raw pointer.

A `shared_ptr` can point to an array. In that case, you index into the array. Don't increment the `shared_ptr`.

If you have a smart pointer to a char array for the purpose of deleting the array when done, you can copy its raw pointer and increment that.

Comment: thank you. so is there no type of smart pointer that we can use arithmetic on ? Do I have to use iterators instead ?

Comment: @canatan Pointers meet the requirements for bidirectional iterators and can be used as such. Since it doesn't look like you need to change what the shared pointer actually points to just use `shared_ptr::get` to acquire a naked pointer _then_ iterate over the string using _that_ pointer value.

Comment: You can copy the smart pointer's raw pointer and increment that. The smart pointer's purpose is to delete the memory node at the right time so **it must point to the start of the memory node.** You could create another kind of smart pointer that holds a current pointer as well as the memory node base pointer. What's the reason you're trying to increment the smart pointer?

Comment: @Jerry101 Just wanted to map very simple code using recursion to smart pointers and this is what came to mind.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Is the time to use smart pointers when you need lists etc and even in the simpler no smart pointers case is it wiser to just use arrays or vectors ?

Comment: @canatan I see. The thing is, smart pointers don't substitute for raw pointers in that way. Raw pointers are more general but don't help with memory deallocation. Use a smart pointer to handle deallocation, and use a raw pointer for pointer arithmetic or (better yet) stop using pointer arithmetic and instead use indexing and `string`.

Comment: @canatan Smart pointers express ownership and manage the lifetime of objects with dynamic storage duration. Any time you find yourself typing `new` you should stop yourself and use a smart pointer and preferably instantiate the object through `std::make_shared` or `std::make_unique` (C++14). In some cases it makes more sense to just use `std::vector` or `std::array` (say for a buffer). It'll take a while for you to learn to use them effectively but there's plenty of information out there to help you along the way.